# Distributed parameters of an unknown conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission

I have been asked in my assignment to find the values of the four distributed parameters R, L, G, and C for the following transmission line:

> A 790 m length of 50 Hz power transmission line is represented by a
>   symmetrical 'nominal PI' equivalent circuit. The series impedance Z
>   consists of a resistance of 12.3 ohms in series with an inductance of
>   1.49 mH, and the parallel branches at each end consist of 1.8 nF capacitors.

Now I think there there is something missing in the line description. Shouldn't I be given the conductor material i.e. its conductivity, permeability, etc.?

Comment: Maybe assume conductivity is zero?

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't make sense because, based on given equations in textbook, the values of R and G become infinite and zero respectively.

Comment: I don't mean for R.